# Error occurred in deployment step 'Install app for SharePoint': The System Account cannot perform this action

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, windows-server

We have installed SharePoint server 2013 in windows server 2008 machine.
For development environment we have visual studio 2012 on windows 7 machine and installed office development tools to develop SharePoint 2013 WebParts.

We are able to link the site which is on remote server and after saying deploy solution it's giving error as

> Error occurred in deployment step 'Install app for SharePoint': The
>   System Account cannot perform this action.

Please help us on this

Thanks.

Comment: I would look in the ULS logs for more clues. To get more information from the logs, switch the output to verbose in powershell by issuing the command : "set-splogfile -traceseverity verbose"

Comment: Also, windows server 2008 is not supported by SharePoint 2013. You need R2 as a minimum.

Answer (score 0):

It seems a security feature of SP 2013. You can try to use a different account which is not system account. Check similar issue here : http://techforum.extreme-sharepoint.com/2013/01/02/error-occurred-in-deployment-step-install-app-for-sharepoint-the-system-account-cannot-perform-this-action/

Comment: Now i tried to execute with different credentials. I am able to avoid system account issue but i am getting another issue like "Apps are disabled on this site"

Comment: Have you found the solution for this problem?

Comment: The link in this answer is no longer active